# Display raw formatted json from a .NET Web API

Tags: c#, json, vba, asp.net-web-api

I know that this has been talked about before but I'm not getting it to work.  I have a .NET WEB API with

```
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
```

in my WebApiConfig.

my url is

```
     https://restapi20190104050748.azurewebsites.net/api/pmid_Impact/30931705
```

my function is

```
       Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

        Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)
        Dim writer As JsonWriter = New JsonTextWriter(sw)


                  While reader.Read
                    writer.WriteStartObject()
                    writer.WritePropertyName("pmid")
                    writer.WriteValue(reader("PMID").ToString)
                    writer.WritePropertyName("issn")
                    writer.WriteValue(reader("issn").ToString)
                    writer.WritePropertyName("essn")
                    writer.WriteValue(reader("essn").ToString)
                    writer.WritePropertyName("journal")
                    writer.WriteValue(reader("journal").ToString)
                    writer.WritePropertyName("pubYear")
                    writer.WriteValue(reader("pubYear").ToString)
                    writer.WritePropertyName("ImpactFactor")
                    writer.WriteValue(reader("ImpactFactor").ToString)
                    writer.WriteEndObject()
                End While
         writer.Close()
                Return sb.ToString
```

and my return value is an ugly,

```
   "[{\"pmid\":\"30931705\",\"issn\":\"2380-0844\",\"essn\":\"2380-0852\",\"journal\":\"JDR Clin Trans Res\",\"pubYear\":\"2019\",\"ImpactFactor\":\"\"}]"
```

how can I get it to look like

```
[{
    "pmid ": "30931705",
    "issn": "2380-0844",
    "essn": "2380-0852",
    "journal": "JDR Clin Trans Res",
    "pubYear": "2019",
    "ImpactFactor": "12.5"
}]
```

This is just a pure web response

Comment: Try `writer.WriteEndObject()`

Comment: Thanks- I added some of my code to show that I do use writer.WriteEndObject().

Comment: with like this you mean the formatting too?, i would suggest using a Json Response Type, right now your response is text/html,

Comment: Where have you got the ugly response from. Is this from some client. The code that you shared looks fine.

Comment: Web API or JSON.NET will never return a string with escaped double quotes. The only way to get this is if the result is a string itself instead of a result object that will get serialized to JSON. Your actual code probably serialized the object *twice*.

Comment: Just return an anonymous type with the propery names and values you want and Web API itself will serialize it to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

VB:

```
Public Function List(ByVal data As Object()) As JsonResult
Return Json(data, New JsonSerializerSettings With {
    .Formatting = Formatting.Indented
})
End Function
```

c#

```
 public JsonResult List(object[] data)
 {
     return Json(data, new JsonSerializerSettings
     {
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented
     });
  }
```

I only Tested the C# Part, but this works for me just fine, 
btw i use the Newtonsoft.Json

more infos can be found here: [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.0)